# Create tempt table with stuff (concatenate)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a question regarding creating temporary table in SQL.
Usually I do into #...but this table I use stuff to concatenate and this syntax doesn’t work. 
Is there another way to do this?
My syntax:

```
select orderID
  ,stuff((SELECT ', ' + cast(Ordertqy as varchar(max))
           FROM #c c2
           where c2.orderID = t1.orderID
           FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'') 

from #c  t1
group by orderID
```

Comment: You can also create temp tables with the CREATE TABLE statement.

Answer (score 1):

Alias your expression:

```
select orderID
  ,stuff((SELECT ', ' + cast(Ordertqy as varchar(max))
           FROM #c c2
           where c2.orderID = t1.orderID
           FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'') as s
into #temp
from #c  t1
group by orderID
```